# Finding a polygonal approximation of a Closed Path

Tags: javascript, image-processing, geometry, curve-fitting, feature-detection

I'd like to be able to find the best fitting polygonal approximation of a closed path (could be any path as they're being pulled out of images) but am having issues with how to approach coding an algorithm to find it.

I can think of a naive approach: every x amount of pixels along the path, choose the best fit line for those pixels, then brute force for different starting offsets and lengths and find the one that minimizes the least-square error with the minimum amount of lines.

There's got to be something more elegant. Anyone know of anything? Also, (cringe) but this is going to be implemented in javascript unless I get really desperate, so nice libraries that do things for you are pretty much ruled out, (opencv has a polygonal fitter for instance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D3.js[1](http://d3js.org/) has some [adaptive resampling](http://bl.ocks.org/3795544) code that you might be able to use. There's also an illustrated [description of the algorithm](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/simplify/) used (Visvalingam’s algorithm).

Comment: Ended up implementing Visvalingam’s algorithm, like D3, since it had such a clear intuitive understanding. Thanks both of you for the suggestions!

Comment: This looks simple enough (which is good) and the example is very nice, interesting. Till this time I haven't needed to implement polygonal approximation (used ready implementations), only shape approximation in general -- which can be done using Fourier descriptors. In terms of compression, I guess this proposed method can't beat the one by Fourier descriptors unless the shape boundary is completely lost, or is that not the case ? (Just curious.)

Answer (score 1):

The [Ramer–Douglas–Peucker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) algorithm seems appropriate here, and is simple to implement.
Note that the acceptable error is an input to this algorithm, so if you have  a target number of lines you can binary-search using the error parameter to hit the target.

Comment: Looks good as well, but the ability to specify the amount of lines desired in Visvalingam's algorithm, made me go with it.

Comment: Bear in mind that removing the smallest-area triangle at each step may not be optimal behaviour, depending on your input data. For instance, a very long, very thin spike extending from an otherwise straight line will have a small area, but is a very noticeable feature of the line that you may wish to preserve.

Comment: Right now I'm happy with the results, the purpose of this is purely visual bitmap vectorization of images so most shapes already tend to be well behaved. If issues come up, I'll definitely take a look.